# What is the appropriate jsp file type association in Android Studio?

Tags: jsp, google-app-engine, android-studio, file-association

I am going through the [Google App Engine (GAE) tutorial for Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction). My GAE project will be tightly coupled to an Android app and as such I am hoping to use Android Studio as my IDE to keep the projects closely aligned.

I have successfully added a GAE module to my project in Android Studio, but when I went to add my first `jsp` file I was prompted with the `Register New File Type Association` dialog:

[image: register file association android studio jsp]

What is the "right" choice for Android Studio? Is there an Android Studio plugin I can add to have `jsp` files understood? What is the appropriate jsp file type association in Android Studio?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to use Android Studio for developing jsp apps.  I've been using regular IntelliJ for that.

Comment: so with regular intellij Will we be able to work on the backend module alone without making changes in the project structure?

Answer (score 0):

google refused to support it... 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164613

so i choose the second option to use external application "Sublime Text" to open JSP files at android studio...

Comment: does this sublime text provide code completion and suggestion? Without affecting the project structure at android studio?